# The Wedding Planner

Tags: algorithm

I was doing a problem for 6.006 MIT OpenCorseWare and it's the problem #6 in the link below: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/exams/MIT6_006F11_final.pdf

The problem itself is easy but I wanted to know how to solve the problem if I tweak the problem little bit.

Given:

- a list of guests V
- lookup table T, where T[u] for u ∈ V is a list of guests that u knows
  (if u knows v, then v knows u)

Problem:

- Arrange the seating such that any guest at a table knows every other guest sitting at the same table either directly or through <strike>some</strike> one other guest sitting at the same table.
- Find the minimum number of tables needed to achieve this requirement

In the original problem you could know the other guests through any number of guests sitting at the same table. But I want to know how to solve this if you could only know the other guests through only one other guest sitting at the table.

What would be the best algorithm for this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this isn't really a site for general programming discussions, and your question is a bit too broad. You should try doing something on your own and come back if you have a specific problem with your code.

Comment: Not too broad by [algorithm] standards. Voting to reopen.

Comment: So what happens if the question is put on hold? I'm not trying to code. I am just trying to solve a problem in algorithms class. If this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533472/algorithm-for-highest-value-inside-budget) is valid, mine should be fine, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's NP-hard. There's a polynomial-time reduction from the NP-hard problem [Clique Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem), one of Karp's original 21, that consists of transforming the graph that is the input to Clique Cover by subdividing each edge and connecting each pair of new vertices, so that every new vertex is at distance ≤2 from every vertex, and two distinct old vertices are at distance ≤2 if and only if they are adjacent in the input.

There's an easy reduction from this problem to Clique Cover, so the best algorithm that I can suggest is to follow this reduction by an exponential-time dynamic program for Clique Cover.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Create a graph with vertices representing the guests. Create edge between each vertex if they know each other(based of table T).

Now all you have to find is the number of connected components.
A connected component is a set(S) of vertices where there exist a path between any two vertices in the set(S).

Number of connected components is equal to number of tables you need.

Comment: That is the answer to the original problem, not the tweaked one. But thanks!

Comment: my bad, I just read the Given/Problem section of the question. Should have read the whole thing. Damn the short attention span.