# Algorithm for highest value inside budget

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I wasn't entirely sure the best way to ask this question (or do the research to see if it has been previously answered).

Given a data set where each entry has a Point value and a Dollar value, I'm looking to generate a list of length N entries that yields the highest aggregate Point value whilst staying within budget B.

Example data set:

```
Item    Points    Dollars
Apple   3.0       $1.00
Pear    2.5       $0.75
Peach   2.8       $0.88
```

And with this (small) data set, say my budget (B) is $2.25, and list length (N) must be 2. You MUST use the fixed list length, but are **not** required to use ALL of the budget.

Obviously the example provided is easy to do in one's head, but given a much larger data set, and both higher N and B values, I'm looking for an algorithm that can generate the list. Having a hard time wrapping my head around this one.

Just looking for a pseudo-algorithm, but if you prefer any given language feel free to respond with that!

Comment: this is the Knapsack problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: It does appear to be the Knapsack problem. Thanks very much for the link!

Comment: Note that Knapsack is pretty easy as far as hard problems go. If there's significant variability in the Points/Dollars ratio, then it's likely that integer program solvers can find the optimal solution reasonably quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite positive that this can be reduced to an NP-complete problem and hence it's not really worth trying to develop a process that will always give you the 'correct' answer as many people have tried and failed to do this efficiently over a large data set. However, you can use a much more efficient approximation technique that whilst it will not guarantee to give you the correct answer, many popular approximation algorithms are capable of achieving a high degree of accuracy.

Hope this helps you out :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-Complete (NP and NP-Hard), meaning, that until now there is no algorithm found, that solves this problem in a polynomial amount time (polynomial to the input size) and if you find an algorithm that does, you would have solved one of the greatest problems in computer science (P=NP), which would you at least bring a million dollar reward.

If you are satisfied with an approximation, I would recommend the Greedy-Algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm